# Largest region where a complex function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

This is my problem:

> Give the largest possible regions in the complex plane where the following four functions are analytic:
>
> a) $\frac{1}{z}$
>
> b) $\ln(z)$
>
> c) $(z-i)^\frac{1}{2}$
>
> d) $\text{Re}(z)$
>
> For functions use the convention $-\pi < Arg(z) \leq \pi$.

For the first one using Cauchy-Riemann equations yields that function is analytic everywhere except at origin, for the second one i know it should be analytic everywhere except at origin and along branch cut, but i'm having trouble proving this for branch cut, for the third one it should be analytic everywhere except where $ z-i=0$ but i'm having some trouble proving that too, and for the last one, is it analytic nowhere?

Comment: Your answers for a and d are correct (for d, go via the Cauchy Riemann equations). For both b and c you will need to make a branch cut.

Comment: How do i make a brach cut?

Comment: I mean i know the ln(z) function using the argument definition should have a branch cut on the negative real axis and a branch point at the origin, but i’m not sure how to prove this or how to prove that ln(z) would be analytic everywhere except along the branch cut or the branch point

Comment: Since $\arg z$ is explicitly specified, you should make a branch cut along the negative real axis for b and that is the only choice.

Comment: for $c$ since $-\pi < Arg(z) \leq \pi$ write $\ln z = \ln re^{i\theta} = \ln r + i\theta$ and verify the Cauchy Riemann equations in poolar coordinates. and for $d$ you could conlcude that it's nowhere analytic just by computing ${ \partial \text{Re}(z) \over \partial \overline{z} } $ which is ${1 \over 2} \neq 0$

Comment: yea see what you mean, but how would you prove that for $\theta = \pi $ the CRE are not satisfied?

Comment: Suppose you define $\ln z = \ln r + i \theta$ for $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$. You can show that $\ln z$ is not continuous along the negative real axis (and of course at the origin), and so is not analytic there. A similar thing occurs for $z^{1/2}$, where the location of the "line of discontinuity" (aka branch cut) depends on how you choose to define $z^{1/2}$ in different regions of the complex plane.